# Limit flutter app for screen sizes in google play console

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, google-play-console

Is there anyway to limit flutter app for devices only with HD,FHD,QHD resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

> I would suggest you to use this for android build to limit app on
> the basis of specific sizes and densities only

```
<manifest ... >
    <compatible-screens>
        <!-- all small size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="small" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
        <!-- all normal size screens -->
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
        <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    </compatible-screens>
    ...
    <application ... >
        ...
    <application>
</manifest>
```

**Full documentation here**

https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution